# Currency not on a record: Ravendb

Tags: ravendb

It's been a turmoil with this exception.

Error request currency not on record

> {"Url:
>   \"/bulk_docs\"\r\n\r\nMicrosoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentNoCurrentRecordException:
>   Currency not on a record\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err) in
>   C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\Api.cs:line
>   2739\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.JetRetrieveColumn(JET_SESID sesid,
>   JET_TABLEID tableid, JET_COLUMNID columnid, Byte[] data, Int32
>   dataSize, Int32 dataOffset, Int32& actualDataSize, RetrieveColumnGrbit
>   grbit, JET_RETINFO retinfo) in
>   C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\InternalApi.cs:line
>   114\r\n   at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.RetrieveColumn(JET_SESID
>   sesid, JET_TABLEID tableid, JET_COLUMNID columnid, RetrieveColumnGrbit
>   grbit, JET_RETINFO retinfo) in
>   C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\RetrieveColumnHelpers.cs:line
>   144\r\n   at
>   Raven.Storage.Esent.StorageActions.DocumentStorageActions.EnsureDocumentEtagMatchInTransaction(String
>   key, Nullable`1 etag) in
>   c:\\Builds\\RavenDB-Stable\\Raven.Database\\Storage\\Esent\\StorageActions\\Util.cs:line
>   58\r\n   at
>   Raven.Storage.Esent.StorageActions.DocumentStorageActions.AddDocumentInTransaction(String
>   key, Nullable`1 etag, RavenJObject data, RavenJObject metadata,
>   TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Storage\Esent\StorageActions\Documents.cs:line
>   502\r\n   at
>   Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c_*DisplayClass46.b*_3f(IStorageActionsAccessor
>   actions) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line
>   709\r\n   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1
>   action) in
>   c:\\Builds\\RavenDB-Stable\\Raven.Database\\Storage\\Esent\\TransactionalStorage.cs:line
>   477\r\n   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Put(String key,
>   Nullable`1 etag, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata,
>   TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line
>   664\r\n   at
>   Raven.Database.Extensions.CommandExtensions.Execute(ICommandData self,
>   DocumentDatabase database) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Extensions\CommandExtensions.cs:line
>   25\r\n   at
>   Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c_*DisplayClassf8.b*_f4(IStorageActionsAccessor
>   actions) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line
>   1658\r\n   at
>   Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action)
>   in
>   c:\\Builds\\RavenDB-Stable\\Raven.Database\\Storage\\Esent\\TransactionalStorage.cs:line
>   526\r\n   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1
>   action) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Storage\Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line
>   502\r\n   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Batch(IEnumerable`1
>   commands) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line
>   1654\r\n   at
>   Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.Batch(IHttpContext
>   context) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\DocumentBatch.cs:line
>   100\r\n   at
>   Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.Respond(IHttpContext
>   context) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\DocumentBatch.cs:line
>   39\r\n   at
>   Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line
>   849\r\n   at
>   Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx)
>   in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line
>   595\r\n"}

This is what i get when i update or even read a particular document. I've even tried deleting the document from database through raven studio though it is showing me  the same  error the document couldn't be done anything(update,delete) it is fully locked. What could have caused the problem? i have no idea on it as what causes it.

Comment: what build are you using?

Comment: It's RavenDB-Build-2230 Ayende.. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: Please try with build 2360 or highet

Comment: Well that's informative... I'm trying to debug this using ManagedEsent and *not* RavenDB ;-)